# How to create numpy zeroes array with variable lengths?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have this array of variable length and I would like to recreate it using np.zeroes or np.empty

```py
narr = np.asarray([["0",[0,0,0,0,0]],["0",[0,0,0,0,0]],["0",[0,0,0,0,0]],["0",[0,0,0,0,0]]])
```

the closest I got was this:

```py
naz = np.zeros([4,2,5,1])
```

But in this case I have multidimensional arrays instead of just 1 element as naz[0][0]

Is it possible at all? How can I do that?

Comment: *variable length array of arrays* doesn't go very well with numpy arrays. While numpy does support them, you wouldn't get much of vectorization benefit in performance, if at all, over the vanilla Python lists.

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of `narr`?

Comment: If you want a non-rectangular array, look for a different library, e.g. Awkward1.

Comment: You could make a`np.zeros` with matching dtype and shape.  But I think you'll need fill the custom elements, the string '0' and the lists of 0s.